# Change Variable based on Cell Clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I want to set a variable to different string when a certain CollectionView cell is tapped. So cell1 is tapped then `var cellTapped = "cell1"`, cell 2 is tapped then `var cellTapped = "cell2"` and so on. It was suggested that I

> "create a custom cell and hold the value as property and read this
>   value on didSelectCell()"

but I'm not sure how to do this (newbie).

(Swift 3)

Comment: Are `cell1` and `cell2` just samples. If that's all you need then it's a simple matter of appending `indexpath.row` to 'cell' prefix.

Comment: There would be alot more cells but naming and setting the var like that would be fine. but what i dont know is where/how do i set it to recognise  that cell1/cells2/cell3/cell4... was tapped. If you had some sample code on something like this it'd help alot @toddg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `UICollectionViewDelegate` to your ViewController and then implement `didSelectItemAt IndexPath` that gets called when a cell is tapped.

Something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellTapped = "cell" + String(indexPath.row)
}
```

You could also have an array of Strings and index into the array based on the `indexPath.row`:

```
let cellStringValues = ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", ... , "celln"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellTapped = cellStringValues[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: When I try and get the variable in the next view it doesn't work. In the second VC I've got let `CV = CollectionViewController()` then in `viewDidLoad()`  I've got `lbl.text = CV.cellTapped ` it just doesn't give a value.

Comment: You'll need to pass the value from the first VC to the second VC. Creating another CollectionView in the second VC isn't going to give you the value that you tapped in a previous view.

Answer (score 1):

Setup your view controller to be the delegate of the UICollectionView. Your view controller should inherit from UICollectionViewDelegate. Then in the viewDidLoad() for the VC set the delegate variable for the UICollectionView to be the ViewController. To catch selection events override the following UICollectionViewDelegate function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellTapped = "cell\(indexPath.row)"
}
```

Check out https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started for more details on working with collection views